# I want to print only date not time after using @sys.date without using webhook in dialogflow

Tags: nlp, dialogflow-es

> > user phrase - I want to travel on 14th jan 2020.
> >
> > response - so, you want to travel on 2020-01-14T12:00:00+05:30

here, I want to response as follow -

> > response - so, you want to travel on 2020-01-14

I don't want to use dialogflow.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To be able to help you, please show us the code that you have tried so far. Please check [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are catching a **@sys.date** entity and not a **@sys.date-time** ?

According to [Dialogflow System Entities Documentation](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/system-entities) **@sys.date** should return:

> @sys.date matches common date references such as "January 1, 2015" or “The first of January of 2015” and returns a reference value in ISO-8601 format: "2015-01-01"

[image]